# File not found in any installed package: %simics%/targets/qsp-x86/images/SIMICSX58IA32X64_1_0_0_bp_r.fd

Tags: simics

I am trying to follow the getting started guide.

First, I installed simics like this:

```
./ispm packages --install-bundle   $HOME/simics-6-packages-2021-24-linux64.ispm  --install-dir $HOME/simics
```

```
% cd simics/ && ls 
simics-6.0.89  simics-oss-sources-6.0.41  simics-pkg-mgr-tmp  simics-qsp-clear-linux-6.0.9  simics-qsp-cpu-6.0.1  simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44  simics-training-6.0.pre14
```

Then, I am trying to run `targets/qsp-x86/firststeps.simics` but get file not found errors:

```
kcc:~/simics > cd simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44/
kcc:~/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44 > ~/simics/simics-6.0.89/bin/simics
Intel Simics 6 (build 6103 linux64) Copyright 2010-2021 Intel Corporation


Use of this software is subject to appropriate license.
Type 'copyright' for details on copyright and 'help' for on-line documentation.

simics> run-command-file targets/qsp-x86/firststeps.simics
/usr/local/google/home/kcc/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44/targets/qsp-x86/qsp-images.include:10:8: Script argument spi_flash_image: File not found in any installed package: %simics%/targets/qsp-x86/images/spi-flash.bin
/usr/local/google/home/kcc/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44/targets/qsp-x86/qsp-images.include:3:8: Script argument bios_image: File not found in any installed package: %simics%/targets/qsp-x86/images/SIMICSX58IA32X64_1_0_0_bp_r.fd
Error - interrupting script.
simics>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Strange, that you've not been caught by different checks.
So first, never run Simics manually within installation folder(s). You should **always run Simics from a Simics project**.

To create a new Simics project, do something like this:

```
$ cd $HOME 
$ $HOME/simics/simics-6.0.89/bin/project-setup my-new-project
$ cd my-new-project
$ ./simics
```

If you're doing this in some already existing folder with some files inside then add `--ignore-existing-files` like this:

```
$HOME/simics/simics-6.0.89/bin/project-setup --ignore-existing-files
```

Now, this folder is Simics's project space that can be individually configured against available Simics installation(s). In its root it has shortcut to run Simics as `./simics`.

Then you can run some target script, also linked from this project space back to your installation:

```
./simics targets/qsp-x86/firststeps.simics
```

this way, you can add targets scripts in the project space without having to change the installation. For example, to use your own BIOS/UEFI image by create a new file `$HOME/my-new-project/targets/qsp-x86/firststeps-my-uefi.simics` that would contain code like this:

```
## [SIMICS PROJECT]/targets/qsp-x86/firststeps-my-uefi.simics
$my_bios_image = <path-to-bios-binary>
run-command-file "%simics%/targets/qsp-x86/firststeps.simics bios_image=$my_bios_image
```

Comment: You should really use the ISPM in GUI mode to easily setup a Simics Project.  But the key is to always run Simics from a project, as @Kovalex has noted.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yea, this way the simple command lines work. I don't have the `targets/qsp-x86` directory in the project, but was able to start `./simics targets/cosim/queues-in-cosimulator.simics`

Comment: Using GUI, I can get the project created with targets/qsp-x86. But the CLI project-setup creates a project only with two subdirs in targets: cosim and  vacuum. How do I create a project using CLI project-setup that would contain targets/qsp-x86?